# Resize de un textarea mediante el teclado

Tags: javascript, html

Estuve investigando sobre el tema y me encontré con un código, el cual no estaría funcionando.
A la hora de apretar ctrl + enter o ctrl + backspace no hace el resize. Lo curioso es que lo probé en codepen y sí funcionó.

```js
var instrumentTextarea = function (textarea) {
    var centerTextarea = function () {
        if (textarea.scrollIntoView) { textarea.scrollIntoView(false) }
        else { textarea.wrappedJSObject.scrollIntoView(false) }
    }
    var textareaKeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) 
        {  textarea.rows -= 1; centerTextarea() }
        else if (e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 32) 
        {
             textarea.cols -= 1; centerTextarea();
        }
        else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
          if (textarea.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight - 40) { textarea.rows += 1; } centerTextarea();
        }
        else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 32) {
          if (textarea.offsetWidth < window.innerWidth - 40) { textarea.cols += 1; } centerTextarea();
        }
    };
    textarea.addEventListener("keydown", textareaKeydown, 0);
}
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"); for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) { instrumentTextarea(textareas[i]); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Text Area Sizing</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <textarea name="textarea" rows="20" col="1000"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal? Estoy con el proyecto de Accesibilidad(muy interesante) y es uno de los pocos cambios que me faltan hacer.

Desde ya aprecio su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar (era una estupidez).

Tenía que mover el  al final del body.

Igualmente dejo la publicación por si a alguien le sirve este código.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en realidad es que solamente fue un error de colocación del <script>. El mismo funcionó.